# How to make TODO and FIXMEs show up in a particular order in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want to make a skeleton application for some students, and I want to be able to direct the order in which the `//TODO` Task tags appear in the `Task List View`.

This is necessary so that the order in which the students will do the tasks actually teaches them something, rather than confusing them and having them spend too much time on understanding the application, rather its parts.

Is there any way to do this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the Tasks list by clicking on the column headings. So if you make your TODO text sort in the order you want you can click on the Description header to get that sort.

Starting the TODO text with a number would be one way to get the TODO to sort:

```
// TODO 001 First todo

// TODO 002 Second todo
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simple solution is just to add a number to the description.

`//TODO 1. Fix this`

`//TODO 2. Fix this later`

Then when sorting the tasts according to description they will appear in the order you choose.